# BlendMode data in a bitamp

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, bitmap

I'm working on a viewer that extracts bitmaps from a .swf file. They're all defined as classes, so I can get them with:

```
getBitmap = event.target.applicationDomain.getDefinition(name);
getBitmap = new getBitmap;
```

These are all different parts of an image and I've to rebuild it. I'm almost done, the only thing that's missing is the blend mode. Now, I've no idea where to get the blend mode from. Some parts do have just a normal blend mode and there are parts which have a different blend mode.

First off, I've no idea if it's even possible that a blendMode is defined in a bitmap. Is there a way to get all informations out of it?

Answer (score 1):

No it's not possible if it's actually just a Bitmap that means it's literally a map of the image, like a Cartesian graph of coordinates to color values, that is literally a bitmap (well with regard to image bitmaps).  Image files in other formats are simply encoded versions of said bitmap to reduce memory size in most cases (colors can be RGB or RGB plus Alpha).  Blend mode (in flash) is a matter of interaction between multiple objects at run-time, it is to say how do you compute the display value based on the mixture of multiple objects.  If you so choose you could set a blend mode on some object, overlay it on another, draw the resulting container to a bitmap then extract the color information, however when you store an image there is no sense of blend mode associated with it (unless it's some proprietary format like PSD or something but not in any of the common image formats).  The only value that relates to the "blend" in the case of a bitmap would be the alpha value which determines how much of a color behind the object will affect the display color of that pixel, or rather how much that pixel will affect the color it's laid over.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BlendMode.html

^notice blend mode is a property of DisplayObject, which BitmapData does not extend from, therefore despite any other knowledge it's obvious that the BitmapData itself has no blendMode the only bit of info you'll find in the BitmapData docs on blendMode is with regard to the draw method in which case the blendMode is used to set the pixel values but subsequently is not an accessible property of the BitmapData.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html

Just thought I would toss in a couple more details for the uber nerds (those undoubtedly roiling at my lack of reference to CMYK and color spaces).  I know you can use other color models such as CMYK which is subtractive instead of additive and is the method used in print, however for displays it's all translated into some sort of RGB since light works in an additive nature.  The RGB may be 8-bit aka 256 color, 16-bit 65,536 colors, 24-bit 16,777,216 colors, or 32-bit 4,294,967,296 colors (if A is included it is another bit depth factor that increases the color space, however A is really the only thing related to "blending").  I'm almost positive anything higher is beyond 32-bit is above our threshold to distinguish, not to mention the way the mind works with visual data via relative changes it probably isn't as important as the relationship between the colors (contrast).

Beyond the color model there are color spaces which map the values to actual colors displayed (buddy of mine told me this was tweaked in some version of Android Honeycomb to reduce the saturation which some people liked and others were angered by).

This ultimately bleeds into biology and the study of cones and rods and how photons stimulate them and how they interact with one another then how this information is encoded in the nerve bundle in the eye how it is sent through the visual cortex and ultimately how our brains interpret those signals, this varies among humans due to differences in all layers of said biology and head development.  Anyhow this is getting way out of my personal nerd realm of expertise so I'll leave it hear for biology nerd to expand if they'd like.  Seems to be pretty good explanations here: http://webvision.med.utah.edu/book/part-ix-psychophysics-of-vision/the-primary-visual-cortex/ though it takes far more understanding than I have the time to delve into.

The other part that's interesting to me is the ability of hardware to accurately re-create whatever is ultimately the value determined after the color space is applied.  All electronic components have some level of error/variability (much like our eyes/brains) so undoubtedly there will be variances based on the hardware and even the operating temperature and other environmental factors.  Anyhow I'm sure I've now plunged far too deep, let me know if the first bit doesn't answer your question.